# matplotlib GUI tooltip

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, tooltip

everytime i use matplotlib GUI on mac it leaves some text on screen.

For example "Zoom Rectangle" tooltip appears on all windows ... and doesn't go away until I have closed python and matplotlib. It's very irritating to do this again and again. I just want to know weather it's problem with my stupid Macbook Air or something to do with matplotlib GUI!

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem.  I haven't been able to fix it yet, but the following has helped.  If you place your cursor over one of the icons (so that the tooltip appears) all of the other zombie tooltips will disappear.  Then, move your mouse off of the icon and wait for the tooltip to completely disappear before closing the figure window.  It is still crazy annoying, but at least you won't have to close python and matplotlib.